# Android Robolectric check if edit text is showing error message

Tags: android-testing, robolectric

I have an editText and a button. On click of the button, if the editText is empty it should set an error message to the editText. I am not getting how to test this scenario using Robolectric. This is my code `

```
// to check if the fields are empty   
   @Override
    public boolean validate() {

        if(edtEmail.getText().toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("")){
            showErrorMessage(true);
            return false;
        }

        if(edtPassword.getText().toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase(null)){
            showErrorMessage(false);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

// to set error message to edittext

    @Override
    public void showErrorMessage(boolean email) {
        if(email){
            edtEmail.setError("Enter Correct Email Id");
        } else {
            edtPassword.setError("Enter Correct Password");
        }
    }   

// on click of button

        btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(validate()) {
                    mPresenter.login(edtEmail.getText().toString().trim(), edtPassword.getText().toString().trim());
                }
            }
        });
```

`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
assertThat("Enter Correct Email Id",edtEmail.getError().toString());
```